# In GTA Chinatown Wars for iPhone is it possible to park the Rhino?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-chinatown-wars

When you purchase the Rhino in BOABO, is it possible to park this anywhere and save?

I've tried taking it to a couple of hideouts, but it says something along the lines of 'this is too big to park here'.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no way to save it. I believe some large vehicles can be saved using the "[chevron bypass method](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vqYvqulQ7_U)," but even that won't work for the Rhino.

Comment: I just confirmed that the chevron bypass method works (for other cars) on the iPhone. I will attempt to do this with the Rhino and report back with results.

Comment: I have searched for chevron method and Rhino and it looks like it can be done, but haven't tried it: 'Also, for the Rhino, it is unfortunate that you must apply the chevron bypass method every time you want to re-store it in the garage.'

Comment: @xiaohouzi79 - Interesting, everything I had read said it wouldn't work with the Rhino, but I hadn't tested it myself.

Comment: I have had a few goes and it's a pain, most cars just burn. What I did try was get the indistructable taxi, but every time I'm maneuvering the police get in the way and screw it up. The other thing I am considering is the front end loader, but I don't know if that can be parked normally and I can't remember where to find it.

Comment: I know there is another jamming method for the garage, but I couldn't get it to work on the iPhone. The door flickers open and closed, but I can't get out of my car.

Answer (score -1):

I think you can save it by leaving it outside your apartment and saving the game.

Comment: The question is how to park the Rhino. Saying "you need to park it" isn't really helpful.